# STM32 Rotary Encoder config

Tags: arm, microcontroller

I am trying to use timer 8 in Encoder mode and my setup is as follows.
Pins PC8 and PC9 (timer8) are connected to a cheap 3 terminal encoder that has C pin grounded so pullups are activated on these pins.

```
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM8, ENABLE);
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 0x0FFF;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_EncoderInterfaceConfig(TIM8,TIM_EncoderMode_TI1,TIM_ICPolarity_Falling,
TIM_ICPolarity_Falling);
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM8, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
TIM_Cmd(TIM8, ENABLE);
```

I then read the counter with `temp=TIM_GetCounter(TIM8);`

I have tried all the possible modes and falling/rising combos I can and am getting nothing.
Does the Timer channel have any effect. It is using channels 3 and 4

Comment: Is it normal to configure two pins at the same time with the same GPIO_InitStructure ?

Comment: It seems to work when I do it for other pins so assumed it would be fine here too. I have the encoder working when just reading the pin states and using a case switch and a standard period timer instead of polling so there is nothing wrong with the connections or pin assignments. It is the encoder interface timer config that has me confused and of course the programmers reference manual is little help as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Channels 3 and 4 of T8 cannot be used  in encoder interface mode. So, pins must be pc6, pc7, not pc8, pc9. Anyway cheap encoders work ugly without proper antibounce. You can configure both pins at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes that was what I ended up doing and it works well. It is actually more accurate than the polling method I was using and doesn't seem to need debouncing. The polling method does and it is more difficult to get a good balance between speed and accuracy. I think the encoder interface is actually pretty good.